# BBD features with dates and timestamps

Tags: cucumber, bdd, acceptance-testing, lettuce, user-acceptance-testing

How best to handle timestamps (dates, times, etc...) within feature definitions?

**Example**

> Feature: Message Status
>
> ```
>     In order to record activty on a message
>
>     As a administrator
>
>     I want to log when a message was created, delivered, and read by an end user
> ```
>
> Scenario Outline: Message created status
>
> ```
>     Given I have configured an e-mail service
>
>     When I perform a send operation with a message body of:
>
>     """
>       James,
>
>       Fancy meeting for lunch?
>     """       
>    Then I should see a new message with a created timestamp of ?????
> ```

**Environment**

OS: Linux/Mac

Language: [Python 2.7.5](https://www.python.org/)

BDD framework: [lettuce.py](http://lettuce.it/tutorial/simple.html)

Comment: Did my answer help? Did you find a resolution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When a message has been sent, I have assumed that a user gets shown a message summary screen. If so you could re-write your test as:

```
Given I have configured an e-mail service
When I send a message
Then I should see a sent message summary
And that it was sent in a timely manner
```

First thing I'd do is assert that the message summary is as expected e.g. maybe you show the first twenty characters from the message. If you don't do this then ignore this suggestion.

Next your application may have a non-functional requirement for how long it should take to send a message (e.g. it should take a maximum of ten seconds to send a message). What I'd do first is record the time when the message was sent in the "When I send a message" step definition. Then in the "And that it was sent in a timely manner" step definition I'd assert that the message time shown has a value *within ten seconds* of the time it was sent.

The key point is that the time it takes to send an e-mail is (almost always) non-deterministic hence the reason for testing that it was sent within a certain time range.

Note that I've assumed that your send message process is a synchronous operation i.e. program execution only progresses to the summary page once the message has been sent, though this may not be the case (and it's usually an asynchronous process).